# Adding F# support to Geany

Tags: f#, ide, geany

I've searched everywhere and I seem to be the only human on the planet wanting to do this. I've tried all the usual things, making filetypes.Fs.conf, filetypes.fs, editing the configs, what have you. It always thinks .fs is Forth and I cannot make it stop, even deleting the Forth files in Geany or removing the Forth section in the syntax config won't stop it. In addition I can't get F# to appear in the languages list. If it helps, I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?

Comment: Sorry if I'm a little vague. I want to add F# as a language in Geany. I can't seem to successfully do it, however.

Comment: Maybe get it to use OCaml or standard ML highlighting which should be close to being correct - geany may not actually have F# highlighting.

Comment: I wasn't really worried about the highlighting, more about adding the language in defiance of Forth's extension (.fs). But I suppose recycling OCaml is my only choice.

Comment: Please consider Feature Tracker of Geany instead of posting on SE network for such things. It's off topic here.

Comment: @frlan why is this off-topic?  Questions about using programming tools are specifically on-topic.  The user had trouble finding the right documentation but that doesn't invalidate the question.

Comment: He is asking about a feature of a tool... yes. The feature is not there, so why posting it here and not adding a feature request? It's not about a thing is working

Comment: @frlan He didn't find the documentation saying the feature isn't there, so how could he have known to not post it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[F# is not currently supported by Geany.](http://www.geany.org/Main/AllFiletypes)  The [FAQ](http://www.geany.org/Documentation/FAQ#QQuestions5) points to [this](http://www.geany.org/manual/hacking.html) page, which is the page about extending Geany, for adding support for other languages.